# What's difference between removeAllViews() and removeAllViewsInLayout()

Tags: android, android-layout

I am populating a linear layout dynamically. Depending upon response, I have to clear the past child views and create new views. I have read the document, but still be confused with the couple methods, they all look the same function. Which function I should use.

Comment: same question here. I add a linearlayout in a getview to an other linearlayout. Using RemoveAllViewsInLayout() instead of RemoveAllViews() fixed an issue with me where the added linearlayout was suddenly dissapearing (and after scrolling came back 0_o )

Answer (score 38):

As Scott Biggs points out, the difference is not a big one.  The only difference is that `removeAllViews()` calls `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` afterwards.  The key to why this difference is here is to understand the naming of `removeAllViewInLayout()`. Confusingly, its meaning isn't "remove all views within this view layout."

[If we look at the similar method, removeViewInLayout(), we can understand what it's supposed to mean:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViewInLayout(android.view.View))

> Removes a view during layout. This is useful if in your onLayout() method, you need to remove more views.

So `removeAllViewsInLayout()` actually means "remove all views, and we're calling this method during a layout pass (i.e. onLayout())". That's why `removeAllViewsInLayout()` doesn't call through to `requestLayout()`, as it's assumed that you're already currently inside a layout pass, so requesting another layout pass is unneeded.

If you use `removeAllViewsInLayout()`, then it's your responsibility to ensure that you're calling this during a layout pass, or to properly call `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` as needed.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the deep explanation!  Perhaps they should have called it, `removeAllViewsDuringLayoutConstruction()` to avoid the ambiguous use of the preposition, _in_.  And maybe a bit of documentation would have helped.  Nahh, docs that complete would give programmers a heart attack. :)

Answer (score 21):

`removeAllViews()` : Call this method to remove all child views from the ViewGroup.
`removeAllViewsInLayout()` : Called by a ViewGroup subclass to remove child views from itself, when it must first know its size on screen before it can calculate how many child views it will render.

Comment: That's a cheery version of what the docs say, which is as clear as mud.  Isn't the View itself (like LinearLayout) a ViewGroup subclass that is removing childs views from itself?  And how do we know if the View must first know its size on screen before it can calculate how many child Views it will render?

Answer (score 13):

Well, looking at the source, there isn't much difference:

```
public void removeAllViews() {
    removeAllViewsInLayout();   // Details implemented here
    requestLayout();
    invalidate(true);
}
```

So unless you want to call `invalidate()` at a time of your choosing, you might as well use `removeAllViews()` and save yourself a bit of typing.

EDIT
For a more detailed explanation, see [David Lui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385205/624814)'s answer. To sum it up, use `removeAllViews()` unless you're in the process of constructing a View--in which case you'd call `removeAllViewsInLayout()`.